# How to limit the amount of times an element can be created

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, createelement

Is there a way to limit the amount of times a user can click a button to create an element? This is what I have managed to put together so far. Thank you.

JavaScript

```
    var ClickCount = 0;

    function countClicks() {
    var clickLimit = 8 ; //Max number of clicks
    if(ClickCount<=clickLimit) {
        populateTipItem();
    }
    else if(ClickCount > clickLimit)
    {
        return;
    }
}

// TIP LIST
function populateTipItem() {

  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "text");
  x.setAttribute("class", "form-control mt-1 tip-item");
  x.setAttribute("placeholder", "Another Tip Item! ... 250tks");
  document.getElementById("tipList").appendChild(x);
  }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="tipList" class="form-group mt-5">
      <label for="tips">Your Tip Menu Items</label>
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Max 10 items.</small>
      <input type="text" name="tips" class="form-control mt-1 tip-item" placeholder="Tip Item! ... 10tks"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="return countClicks()">Add Tip Item</button>
```

Comment: In terms of limiting elements by tag name, you can use document.getElementsByTagName().length to determine if you need to limit the creation of another element of that tag

Comment: Just increase the value of `ClickCount` on every click (as the name already suggests)

Answer (score 4):

You're almost completed. The main change is to add `ClickCount++` so you'll know how much elements were created.

```
var ClickCount = 0;
var clickLimit = 8 ; //Max number of clicks
function countClicks() {
    if(ClickCount<=clickLimit) {
        ClickCount++;
        populateTipItem();
    }
    else if(ClickCount > clickLimit) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! My brain fog was overwhelming, thank you for clearing it for me!

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can count the number of elements created:

```
var clickLimit = 8;
var tipList = document.getElementById('tipList');

function countClicks() {
  if (tipsList.children.length < clickLimit) {
    populateTipItem();
  }
}
```